# CSS disappears when 'DEBUG' Django is turned False

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings, adminlte

I'm working with Django and I'm using a AdminLTE framework for the estilização, but, when I turn the **DEBUG** to **False**, the page shows with pure html.

`DEBUG = True`:
[image]

`DEBUG = False`:[image]

`settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'saga.core',
    'saga.subjects',
    'saga.accounts',
    'saga.tasks',
    'saga.study_time',
    'django_adminlte',
    'django_adminlte_theme',
]
```

**django_adminlte** and **django_adminlte_theme** are the apps for the style framework.

Answer (score 1):

When `DEBUG = True` Django will serve static and media files. When `DEBUG = False` it will not. Therefore all of the js and css files will return a 404 error unless served. For a better of understanding of what is going on i would recommend reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/ These static files may also be present in installed apps and not just within the project itself.

For local testing you can add the following to your `urls.py` `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

`static` can be imported from `from django.conf.urls.static import static`

Further information can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Further information regarding how to deploy static files in production can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: I 'm already using the `static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`, because I' m serving some images. I tried your way, but I'm still having the same problem. Let me explain: the CSS framework is not in a file on a folder, I instaled it like a Django app (see my edit on question).

Comment: In your browser if you right click and inspect the page are there any 404 errors in the console?

Comment: It's the same code, with the same files and importations, I just saw a difference on a input from a form.

Comment: Well, I interrupted the comment because I really don't know what's happening. I was copying the different input, but, now, it's all working normal.

Comment: ***NEWS***: Now, I recived this error mesage: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: <WSGIRequest: GET '/static/admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js'>`

Answer (score 0):

When Debug = False , Django will not recognise the static files such as css and images. To make django aware you can follow the following steps :

1. Install a python library "whitenoise" `pip install whitenoise`
2. In your settings.py , find the middleware and add the file at the end. The file will look like this `MIDDLEWARE = ['', 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',]`
3. On the same settings.py add `STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'production_files`. This will be used by django to create a folder to store all its static files
4. You're almost done , now run the following command to generate the folder we stated above `py manage.py collectstatic`
5. Re start your server and you should be good to go

For more information browse [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_add_static_files.php)